# How to close automatically this jframe loginform and redirect to other forms?

Tags: java, jframe

```js
private void LoginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        
       Welcome a= new Welcome();
            a.setVisible(true);
            a.setDefaultCloseOperation(Welcome.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            
            DBManage db = new DBManage();
            
            if(db.checkUser(textUsername.getText(), textPassword.getText())){
                MESSAGE.setText("Login Successful");
            }else{
                MESSAGE.setText("Wrong Password or Username");
                
            }
            
            
                    
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
    }                                           

public static void main(String args[]) {

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
             
                new LoginForm().setVisible(true);
                
                
                
            }
            
        }); 
    
    }
```

I have this loginform jframe after I have logged in

The welcome frame will pop up, but the loginform is still there.

How do I programmatically close that?

Thank you, I am still a beginner in programming.

Comment: i think it should work to either dispose or set to not visible the login frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to close the login form like so:

```
  public void close(){
     WindowEvent winClosingEvent = new WindowEvent(this,WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
     Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClosingEvent);

   }
```

So call this method after setting the new frame to visible like this:

```
private void LoginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            


        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:

            DBManage db = new DBManage();

            if(db.checkUser(textUsername.getText(), textPassword.getText())){

                Welcome a= new Welcome();
                a.setVisible(true);
                a.setDefaultCloseOperation(Welcome.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                MESSAGE.setText("Login Successful");//I think this line will not be necessary here.

                close(); //<-----------------------------HERE

            }else{
                MESSAGE.setText("Wrong Password or Username");

            }



        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: That problem is from the logic you are implementing in the `checkUser()` method from the `DBManage` class. I don't know whats there so if you can provide whats there, maybe I can help.

Comment: You must set the condition in the `checkUser()` method to return true if both the `username` **AND** `password` matches. Remember to use the `AND` thus (`&&` in you code) operation to ensure that.

Comment: oh i already solve it thank you anyway ill ask something again sooner thanks again for your help

Comment: Alright, you are welcome. Well done anyway because the best way to learn is to figure out things yourself.